# Running existing ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms apps on Mac

Tags: macos, webforms, mono, asp.net-core

Can we run an existing ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms apps like one on Mac using mono:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-221c01f5?cdn_id=2013-12-16-001

I believe I need to use a Mono aware IDE and to try to re-reference all compatible .dlls and try to 
modify the code that doesn't have equivalent in mono versions to use mono libraries.

**Is this true?**

There is an open source questionnaire type of app (different then above app) that I would like to run on Mac. I have a friend with a Mac computer who would like to serve web pages from a web server residing on the Mac (I am not sure what kind of Service would that be - like Mac version of IIS - some kind of daemon service) and when the questionnaire response is submitted he wants a .PDF of that response to be created and saved on Mac local folder (so I need to find a way how to use create .pdf based on posted response data)

vnext version would be fine (which I heard improves all by Web Forms app), but I don't know if Web Forms libraries are available for the Mac

I would like to develop and debug on a Windows machine and just deploy and configure web server on the Mac.

**Is Xamarin Studio for Windows or MonoDevelop for Windows answer?**

**What are best web servers on the Mac that can serve up the pages preferably that are similar in nature to IIS?**

Comment: Have a look at the Mono project http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/ and SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108380/best-way-to-get-started-in-setting-up-mono-for-asp-net-on-mac

Comment: Tx. If I need to start from and existing open source VS 2013 solution which I can build and run using IIS or IISExpress. How do I proceed with compiling it against Mono on Windows and what IDE I can use on Windows? How do I know if Mono on Windows will have be compatible with Mono for OSX? My goal is to compile against Mono on Windows and run it in IIS like web server using Mono runtime on OSX.

Comment: I am familiar with Xamarin Studio on Windows and Mac for cross-phone development, but I never tried building and running asp.net 4+. What web server would Xamarin use on Windows to test/run the code and what it would use on Mac side.

Comment: visualization is least pain, install a windows vm

Answer (score -1):

Use VS 2015 and .Net Core if you want to build .NET applications to run on a Mac.  It is still in preview but you can still develop applications.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. Is there any explanation on how to develop on Windows and deploy it on Mac? Is Mono 4.6 (run time) available on Mac and what web server can I use to run it.

Comment: Rad, because it is so new, you will have to do a little research on how to deploy to a mac.  I know .Net Core can run on a mac without a web server.  Here is some more information on it, I hope it helps and sorry I cant be more useful on this subject.  I am learning it myself.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETasOpenSourceNETonMacandLinuxandVisualStudioCommunity.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know if I can run a WebForms project on existing mono for Mac.

Comment: Web forms is not supported on .Net Core

Comment: @AliGonabadi Are Web forms still not supported?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question (which is a good one).